# Menu text disappears on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, menu, interface

I have a problem on ubuntu 16.04 : sometimes, when I exit my computer from sleep state, I lose all my menu texts. You can see it on screenshots:

[image: Empty Eclipse Window]

[image: Empty Ubuntu message box]

The only solution I found is to reboot my computer.

Does anyone know the cause of this, or a solution?

Comment: See if logging out and back in works. It'll be faster than reboot until the problem is solved.

Comment: Or instead of rebooting completely you can try if a partial reboot fixes it quicker (graphical environment reboot), using the shortcut `Ctrl+Alt+Backspace`

Comment: I will try a partial reboot next time I have the problem ! Thks !

Comment: Partial reboot works well, tks. But if someone know the reason of this problem and how to solve it, it would be better than rebooting.

Comment: Your screenshots are not there anymore, maybe you could upload them directly to the question?